# How to load AngularJS files with appended scripts? (CSP strict-dynamic requirement)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loading, content-security-policy

I'm hosting AngularJS locally. If I load the JS files this way before the closing body tag, it works:

```
<script src="javascript/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/angular.min.js.map" type="application/json"></script>
<script src="javascript/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/angular-route.min.js.map" type="application/json"></script>
```

In order to allow for the new 'strict-dynamic' CSP, I need to load all of my scripts within a single sourceless script (i.e., no 'src' is allowed for script elements on a page; the script itself must be contained within the script tags). For all scripts except for AngularJS, my script loading routine works without issue. If I try to load it this way, it fails with error message in the console ("Cannot read property 'module' of undefined," etc.):

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var loadScript = function (url, type) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        if (type === 'application/json') {
            script.type = type;
        }
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    };

    loadScript('javascript/angular.min.js', '');
    loadScript('javascript/angular.min.js.map', 'application/json');
    loadScript('javascript/angular-route.min.js', '');
    loadScript('javascript/angular-route.min.js.map', 'application/json');
};
</script>
```

This also fails if the routine is not restricted to the window.onload event:

```
<script>
var loadScript = function (url, type) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    if (type === 'application/json') {
        script.type = type;
    }
    document.body.appendChild(script);
};

loadScript('javascript/angular.min.js', '');
loadScript('javascript/angular.min.js.map', 'application/json');
loadScript('javascript/angular-route.min.js', '');
loadScript('javascript/angular-route.min.js.map', 'application/json');
</script>
```

...and it makes no difference if I grab the files from local hosting or from Google's Ajax CDN.

Any clue how to solve this? With the 'strict-dynamic' CSP, I have no choice but to load the AngularJS framework files using a technique like the ones above.